# Clicking "More" button via selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, lazy-loading, webdriverwait

I am trying to scrape the following website : https://angel.co/companies

There is a "More" button at the bottom, which on click loads more records.

I need to click the button via selenium.

I tried the following:

```
python_button = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("more")
python_button.click()
```

However its not finding the appropriate button, i.e. my `python_button` returns an empty list.

I tried the following:

```
python_button = driver.find_element_by_class_name("more")
```

And this gives the following error:

> Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"class
>   name","selector":"more"}

Any ideas to get around this?

Answer (score 4):

The more you will click the **MORE** button more data will be loaded. You need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the button with text with **MORE** *to be clickable* and you can use the following solution:

- Code Block:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

  options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
  options.add_argument("start-maximized")
  options.add_argument('disable-infobars')
  driver=webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path=r'C:\WebDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
  driver.get("https://angel.co/companies")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='more' and contains(.,'More')]")))
  while True:
      try:
          WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='more' and contains(.,'More')]"))).click()
          print("MORE button clicked")
      except TimeoutException:
          break
  driver.quit()
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  MORE button clicked
  MORE button clicked
  MORE button clicked
  MORE button clicked
  MORE button clicked
  MORE button clicked
  MORE button clicked
  MORE button clicked
  MORE button clicked
  MORE button clicked
  MORE button clicked
  MORE button clicked
  MORE button clicked
  MORE button clicked
  MORE button clicked
  MORE button clicked
  MORE button clicked
  MORE button clicked
  MORE button clicked
  MORE button clicked
  ```

Answer (score 1):

I have tried the same using Java. Please add explicit/fluent wait before checking the list size. Please find below the code.

```
driver.get("https://angel.co/companies");
    new WebDriverWait(driver, 30).pollingEvery(Duration.ofMillis(100)).withTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(30))
            .until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("div.more")));
    List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("div.more"));
    System.out.println(elements.size());
```

Comment: Do you have a pythonic version of this?

Answer (score 0):

You are doing right, just wait a little. The ajax triggers after selenium callback.
You can write something like this or use "assert":

```
button = None
while not button:
    button = driver.find_element_by_class_name("more")
    if button:
        break
```

You also can try to use ajaxes instead of selenium. Try this url changing page parameter:

```
https://angel.co/companies/startups?ids[]=81494&ids[]=3322647&ids[]=98145&ids[]=32119&ids[]=21604&ids[]=19935&ids[]=480579&ids[]=3062473&ids[]=431924&ids[]=395542&ids[]=154&ids[]=948481&ids[]=197974&ids[]=891681&ids[]=972236&ids[]=686564&ids[]=115616&ids[]=515341&ids[]=1856&ids[]=477880&total=4381226&page=3&sort=signal&new=false&hexdigest=be1927797c1b88f79ae42efd4180ea78d3e9e711
```

Look, the website returns json file with dictionary of one key - "html", this is the htmlcode servers return.

Comment: Your solution won't allow to *wait a little*. The same exception will be raised