# Unable to scrape all data from angel.co website

Tags: python, screen-scraping

I am trying to extract data from angel.co website. I can able to extract data using selenium. But the site restricted to view only 400 records. How can I view and extract all more than 400 records. Any help would be appreciated

URL : https://angel.co/companies?company_types[]=VC+Firm&company_types[]=Startup&company_types[]=Private+Company&company_types[]=SaaS&company_types[]=Mobile+App&locations[]=1624-California&stage[]=Seed&stage[]=Series+A&stage[]=Series+B&stage[]=Series+C&stage[]=Acquired[image]

Comment: [Clicking “More” button via selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52800174/clicking-more-button-via-selenium)
Exactly the same question has been asked and answered.

Comment: I can able to click the more button , but the problem is i cannot view morethan 400 records

Comment: '<div class="more" data-max_pages="20" data-page="2">More</div>`
Isn't a maximum of 400 cases of 20 cases per page a maximum of 20 pages? It may be a specification.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Is it possible to view all the pages in that link. I am wondering there should be some way to view all the pages.

Comment: I think you should click on it 20 times and then get the data.